# jQuery hover scroll for very long menus

Tags: jquery, scroll, menu

This is loosely based on Chris Coyier's snippet: 
https://css-tricks.com/long-dropdowns-solution/

I'm working on a long-dropdown solution, and I would like to eliminate the extra space at the bottom, and perhaps make it a little easier to click items close to mouse.  Hover over the menu to scroll it.

**Here's the Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/3hanq4wt/1/

The extra space is caused by my JS moving the UL upwards. It will need an improved movement ratio so that so that the UL doesn't move quite so high when scrolling.

I tried several things, such as:

```
     var remainder = containerBottom - ( list.offset().top + listheight ); 
     //this remainder ought to be useful somehow.  Surely it must.
```

I do realize that this is not an ideal UX solution for most cases, but I have a layout that requires fixed height (assigned dynamically) container with  overflow hidden.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this took me quite a while, I'll post solution:

```
multiplier= ( listheight-container.outerHeight() ) / container.outerHeight();
```

Change the multiplier so it uses the actual distance you want to move, divided by the number of cursor pixels in the 'track'.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3hanq4wt/3/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of the extra space in your fiddle by adding some pixels to your offset.

```
containerTop = container.offset().top + 50,
```

or using your listheight variable

```
listheight = list.outerHeight() - 200,
```

Comment: You are correct, my apologies.  I had to set your ul height 21 pixels per list item to remove the extra height.  I will edit my answer with a suggestion as it is incorrect currently.

Comment: No worry, but the extra space is cause by my JS moving the UL upwards.  It will need position adjustment, not height.  

My confusion is how to create the correct movement ratio when scrolling so that it doesn't go quite so high, leaving empty space at bottom.

Comment: ok, edited again, my last shot at it.  You can decrease that space even more by adding a few pixels, +60, 70 etc.  :D

Comment: I tried that too, but since I used list-height as part of the scroll ratio, the number of list-items is inversely related to the extra space at bottom.  Same issue exists in the original version https://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/

Comment: I was able to do it by altering your listheight variable too, edited